# Flutter App gets stuck at loading screen after adding initializing firebase_core

Tags: firebase, flutter

My App get stucked at loading screen after adding Firebase.initializeApp(), without Firebase.initializeApp(), it displays my login screen, but I can't use any of the firebase plugin in my pubspec.yaml file without initializing  firebase_core.

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: themeData(),
      home:Login()
    );
  }
```

Tried this,it loads  the error screen with  the error: future returned null

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class App extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          // Initialize FlutterFire
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // Check for errors
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
               print(snapshot.error.toString);
               return Error();
            }
    
            // Once complete, show your application
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Login();
            }
    
            // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
            return Loading();
          },
        );
      }
    }


pubpec.yaml file
      google_sign_in: ^4.5.5
      uuid: ^2.2.2
      path_provider: ^1.6.21
      firebase_storage: ^5.0.0-dev.2
      firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
      cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+3
      firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
      firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1



flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[v] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
[v] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[v] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[v] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[v] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: What is the error? By the way, you can upgrade your Flutter. 1.22.2 is now on the stable channel. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows

Comment: Returns null when used in 

    FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyAwesomeApp();
        }

Comment: Edit your question with the error. Reading from comments is not easy.

Comment: you've already initialized firebase in your main function. There is no need to use it inside FutureBuilder

Comment: OK,  I edited my question @towhid

Comment: To check the user's login state you need to implement firebase auth.
Follow this tutorial for more detailed view, https://youtu.be/mZYuuGAIwe4

Comment: It looks like the problem is from my project. I created another project and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

After updating initiate firebase call in main.dart it worked for me.

Added 'options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android' inside 'await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android);'

You can try also try with 'await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);'

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(LoginPage());
}
```